# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I have upgraded my android studio .. and I found many problems in the latest version

Although many similar questions exist, I checked the answers to all and none of them worked for me!

error:
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks

Here is the error I'm facing while compiling the code:

**Build.gradle**
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ownmettro.androidecommerce'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111", onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }

    configurations.all {

        resolutionStrategy {

            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

            force 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

            force 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

            force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

            force 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'

            force 'com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.1'

        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'

    implementation 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.+'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: press double shift and type `LoaderCallbacks` in Android studio. You are getting the information, which libraries have same class.

Comment: how can i remove

Comment: which library have same class ?

Comment: android library 27.1.1 and 28.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all caches and re-build by changing below things

```
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
  .....
  targetSdkVersion 27
```

Comment: Nice to hear it.@paraman babu Can u upvote this as well if it helpfull. Happy coding